# document.getElementById returns null after Dynamically generated HTML element

Tags: javascript, jquery, prototypejs

I am using [prototype.js](http://api.prototypejs.org)

After **dynamically generated Input elements** when I do

`document.getElementById()` or `$(Id)`

I get `null`.
UPDATE:

[image]

Comment: at the time of calling document.getElementById or $(Id), does the component exist in the source of page?

Comment: create a [jsfiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net) to explain your question.. nobody can not help with this chunk of code.

Comment: Your element is already appended to DOM, or you just archiving it in a var? If you appended it to DOM, did you wait persist the element creation before search in the document for the ID?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to me like you did not give any id to your input field. it looks like you only have name attribute. you should give it an id attribute too.

Comment: exactly the id is missing from the dom elements

Answer (score 1):

Querying the dom for elements that are dynamicly generated doesn't make a lot of sense.

When you generated the element, save a reference to it. That way your javascript doesn't do a lot of repetitive expensive queries.

To answer you specific question, it should work, and you probably forgot to insert the element into the dom.

Comment: how would i insert it in dom?

Comment: @Ravi ~ oh no. there's your problem. :)

Comment: the id is missing from the elements, as you can see from firebug they are part of the DOM

Comment: The image wasn't part of the question when I answered, so I could only guess.

Answer (score 1):

The element selected with Firebug does not have an ID attribute. Therefore, you won't be able to get it by id.

Answer (score 0):

As per my knowledge you are suppose to writing your `JavaScript` at the top of the page but the element will generate after some execution or after the execution of that java script code.

So in that case particular JavaScript code didn't got that element ID; so it will retrieve a `null` value and send error like that.

If possible just try to call that `JavaScript` at the bottom of the page OR we can say after page get load.. i think this will work for your same code..

Just try it once, if your luck with you then will get your `Element Id`.

Thanks.